# I didn't put an address in ESTA form because I was not sure I was going to stay there

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, esta, italian-citizens

In planning a trip to the US, I booked a "temporary" place, with the idea in mind that I might cancel it later to get a better place.

When applying for the ESTA, I put UNKOWN in the appropriate fields for Point of Contact as I didn't want to put a statement that might became false in the future.

I know that I can update the address on my Esta application, but I was wondering if not doing that (since I've read multiple times that it is not required) would be a problem at the immigration control, given the following scenario:

1. Immigration asks me where I am going to stay
2. I show a receipt of my booking
3. They see that my booking was made prior to the ESTA application and that I put unknown even if I knew where I was going to stay

I am an Italian citizen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It doesn't matter.  "Unknown" is a perfectly reasonable thing to say if you have a booking but haven't decided whether you will actually use it.  Enjoy your trip.